# Link cells in Excel to Access table fields

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

Consider I have a macro in access 2003 that uses the transferSpreadsheet function to export a Union query to a excel 2007 spreadsheet; the exported data depending on a date range input by the user.

Now suppose this UNION ALL Query grouped a table and a query. The query being a LEFT JOIN of a linked table and another table to add missing fields to.

Is it possible to allow updating of the cells in excel to simutaneously update the proper fields of the records in the three tables (Table, Query(2 Tables)) which are part of the Union (which can't be edited directly and only used to get all the information in one table)? If so can someone show me the proper way to do this or at least somewhat guide me in the right direction?

I would like it if while I was exporting and formatting the excel files in vba, I linked the cells. As the end user would not know what to do to link the cells. I ask because the file is generated monthly changed throughout the month into the next month and sometimes is still updated during the next month and both are worked on simutaneously. It would be easier if they where linked so the excel file would not have to be continually generated.

Using:

VBA (not vb.net)

Access 2003

Excel 2007

Comment: `Is it possible to allow updating of the cells in excel to simutaneously update the proper fields of the records in the three tables (Table, Query(2 Tables))` To answer this question - which is your only question in the post - Yes, it is possible!

Comment: lol thanks question adjusted :p

Comment: This is going to be long, tedious and probably not a good idea. You can write some queries and feed them parameters with ADO, but  disaster may be a click away. You can feed the Excel table back to Access and run updates, which may be safer. You will need to try.

Comment: @Remou well I'm unfamilair with that methodology but another problem with using the SQL Update function, which i'm guessing i would use, is that not only does the data have a range depending on date, the table used to generate it is also a union. Once more the ID's are not exported with the rest of the Project Report

Comment: If you have no IDs, you cannot do this in Excel, I can suggest something that would work in Access.

Comment: @Remou I could always export the ID's and then hide the column while i'm formatting the file but i use a union which I don't think their would be a way to create unique ID's from the two main tables which populates the query...What would you suggest?

Comment: Basically, if you have no way of identifying a unique row and possibly no way of identifying a field, you cannot update. Why do you think you need to go along this difficult road?

Comment: It was at a request as what occured previously was a hack and slash of the user exporting the fields to excel, adding the extra columns needed, formatting the excel spreadsheet and filling and updating the excel spreadsheet as time went on, sometimes also updating the access files if the fields exported where changed  by the system planer. what I already have simplified a lot of the process and made it a little easier but I was just wondering if their was a way to go beyond this and perform what was requested. But i understood the limitations and wasn't quite sure if possible

Comment: I cannot really say it is impossible, because I do not know what you are putting into the spreadsheet, but it is beginning to sound impossible.

Comment: lol well thats what i figured the spreadsheet is just a snapshot using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet method of a range of values in query which doesn't have the primary keys of the records i could add and hide them but i figured that since their coming from two tables unique identification wouldn't work properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15605/discussion-between-bonechilla-and-remou)

Answer (score 0):

kdgwill, after performing your transferspreadsheet function, you can then perform the following.  This will take the names of the spreadsheet just saved, manipulate what you need to change, then save it back to Excel with either the same name or new name.  This happens very fast depending on the size of your data.  65,000 rows of data many take a minute to save the file.  You can add data to tables even when calling this function.  Work with this to see if you can manipulate it to your means.

```
Dim objExcel            As New Excel.Application
Dim objWB               As Excel.Workbook
Dim objWS               As Excel.Worksheet
Dim objWS2              As Excel.Worksheet
Dim objCell             As Excel.Range



Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("path of the original excel file\excelfile.xls")

objWB.Activate
'Do not show the excel window during this operation.  By doing this the processing is faster.
objExcel.Visible = False

sSection = "Open Spreadsheet"
If objWB.Worksheets.Count = 0 Then
    objWB.Worksheets.Add
End If

'Open the first sheet named what ever you want to name it
 Set objWS = objWB.Sheets(1)

objWS.Name = "Name of Spreadsheet"
objWS.Activate

'Change the font to black or anything else you want to change
With objWS
    .Cells.Select
    .Cells.Activate
    .Cells.Font.Size = "12"
    .Cells.Font.Color = 0
    .Cells.Range("A1", "A1").Select
End With

    objExcel.Workbooks(1).SaveAs "path of new excel file to be saved\excelfile.xls"

'Clean up 
objWB.Close
Set objWB = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```